# How to spoof/mock a directory used by a binary application as another directory?

Tags: directory

Suppose there's a binary application that always writes its data to `/tmp`.

How could I spoof/mock `/tmp` for the sake of this binary as some other directory (e.g. `home/tmp`)?

Let's assume I have no means of modifying this binary to force it to use a different directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can run the application in a `chroot` environment i.e. the `/` the application sees is not the real `/`. You create a complete new file system hierarchy and mount (`--bind`) everything you need into it. The relevant point is: You can mount the real `~/tmp` to the `/tmp` in the `chroot` environment.

Instead of using `chroot` (which requires superuser privilege) you may do more or less the same with Linux containers (`lxc`). I am not familiar with `lxc` but as it's a normal user process to the host system you do not need to be the superuser for such configurations within the container.

Comment: Great answer, I hadn't heard of either `chroot` or `lxc` being capable of doing this. It's also really nice to know there's a way of accomplishing it without being a superuser.

Comment: @Nobilis 98 upvotes missing for this to be recognized as a great answer...

Comment: Beware, however, that `chroot` requires additional setup (you are replacing the whole of `/`, not just `/tmp`, so any access to `/etc`, `/var`, etc, will also be inside the "jail") and creates security concerns of its own (the "jailed" program may be able to manipulate parts of the file system which would normally be off-limits if you aren't careful with the permissions when setting up your fake `/`).

Comment: @IMSoP Would you mind explaining "may be able to manipulate parts of the file system which would normally be off-limits" in more detail?

Comment: @HaukeLaging If the new `/` is not restricted to be written only by `root`, the "jailed" user can create or replace files which seem to be in key system locations, such as `/etc/passwd`; this can then be used for privilege escalation which would not be possible outside the `chroot`. Many Linux FTP servers, which traditionally use `chroot` to hide the rest of the filesystem, now refuse to do so if the directory is writeable by a non-root user.

Comment: @IMSoP `mount --bind` does not change access rights (except for making the whole mounted tree read-only). And you cannot replace files in a mounted tree. You must be root in order to unmount. You can create a file `chroot/etc/passwd` but this is covered by the mount on `chroot/etc/`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Sure, that's the kind of precaution I meant when I said "if you aren't careful". As far as I know, using `mount --bind` does not in itself create a read-only mount, although it is possible to pass additional options to make it do so, further highlighting the need to know what you're doing when using this technique in a security-sensitive context.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "you cannot replace files in a mounted tree".

Answer (score 8):

Most POSIX compliant software would honor the [TMPDIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMPDIR) environment variable e.g.

```
env TMPDIR=~/mytmp  /path/to/application
```